# Time complexity: confused about the idea of log and floor function

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am confused about this time complexity problem.

Suppose I have an input list L that has a size of n, and I have two recursive calls that are:

```
f(L[:len(L) - len(L)//3 - 1])
f(L[len(L)//3:len(L)-1])
```

I know the size of new input list is reduced each time when the function is recursively called, and I am not sure but I think each time it's reduced by `n - floor(n//3) - 1`, but I also realize that the `len // 3`  should give $\log_3 n$, I am confused by this problem, can someone give me a solution to this question and explain why it works to me?

Comment: Ideally, could you show the complete function? Is there a reason you're slicing instead of using indices? The slices are probably an extra linear factor just to save passing a parameter or two. A bit of context as to what the algorithm does is also nice. Thanks.

Comment: You used the "algorithm" and "time-complexity" tags and not the "python" tag. I assume you believe that the language doesn't matter. But the syntax you use is python slicing syntax, and python slicing is particularly inefficient for recursion, because the slice is a copy that needs to be built, and this has a non-negligible complexity too. Instead, you could just pass the indices as extra arguments to the function, to tell the function to only operate on a subregion of the list. This way, the list never has to be copied.